# Android push notification via Sinch, how to know who tried to contact

Tags: sinch

I was able to create push notification after following this [tutorial](https://www.sinch.com/tutorials/send-push-notifications-android-messaging-app-using-gcm/), but when I click on the notification it opens the messaging app but I dont know who sent a message to me, I wanted to know if there is a way to know who sent it, content of message if possible and if I click on the notification can it directly go to chat with that person.

to see what GCM is sending I added the following to gcmintentservice :

```
public class GcmIntentService extends IntentService {
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;
private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
public GcmIntentService() {
    super("GcmIntentService");
}
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();

         if (action.equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
             handleMessage(intent);
         }

    mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager)
            this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
            new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class), 0);
    NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle("New Message!");
    mBuilder.setContentIntent(contentIntent);
    mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, mBuilder.build());
    GcmBroadcastReceiver.completeWakefulIntent(intent);
}
private void handleMessage(Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        Set<String> keys = bundle.keySet();
        Iterator<String> it = keys.iterator();
        Log.e("message","Dumping Intent start");
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            String key = it.next();
            Log.e("message","[" + key + "=" + bundle.get(key)+"]");
        }
        Log.e("message","Dumping Intent end");
    }
}`
```

}

and the log message I get is :

E/message﹕ Dumping Intent start

E/message﹕ [from=551512823036]

E/message﹕ [android.support.content.wakelockid=2]

E/message﹕ [collapse_key=do_not_collapse]

E/message﹕ Dumping Intent end

but I cant see sender_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the sample backend provided in the tutorial (https://github.com/sinch/push-backend-ruby), you're not sending the sender_id to the server. You'll also need to update the backend logic to handle the incoming sender_id, and include it in the GCM options.

Comment: is there any example for backend?  I am new to ruby and backend server.  I did see options but don't know how to pass information and receive it

Answer (score 0):

Look in the message that you receive, there should be a sender id there.

See here for documentation about the message
http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/index.html
http://download.sinch.com/docs/android/latest/reference/com/sinch/android/rtc/messaging/Message.html

Comment: in the tutorial I can't find where the message is received, any suggestions?

Comment: I searched on how to get sender Id from gcm but seems this is Google project Id, am I searching the wrong keywords